# useEffect is causing infinite loop when use state as dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here simply I am fetching data from mysql DB and storing it in state and in order to fetch this data:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
```

To fetch data I am using different functions and finally I am calling those functions using useEffect simple enough and so for everything is working perfectly but the problem comes whenever I use the state as dependency where I am storing data beacause if I dont do that then I have to manually refresh the page for latest changes and I have tried every given solution on stackoverflow but any of the solution didnt work so someone can please help me how can I use this state as dependencey without causing infinite loop:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
 
  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/k-shop/load.php");
    const result = await response.json();
    setOrders(result);
  };
  const loadTotal = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/k-shop/amount.php");
    const result = await response.json();
    setTotal(result);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
    loadTotal();
  }, [orders]);
  console.log(orders);
```

Comment: You seem to have shown the code that *does* work. Please show the change that makes it *not* work (that causes the infinite render).

Comment: But if you mean you're adding `orders` and/or `total` to the dependencies array, then of course it's going to cause infinite refresh (assuming either of those is an object; looks like `orders` is an array, which is an object) -- it will render, trigger the effect, the effect sets state, causing a render, which triggers the effect, which... If you [search for "too many renders" in the reactjs tag](/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+too+many+renders), you'll find a **lot** of answered questions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the state into the useEffect dependency, you can then check if it is empty, and only set it when that check passes.

It will set the state once to populate and not pass the check again.

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
 
const loadData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost/k-shop/load.php");
  const result = await response.json();
  setOrders(result);
};

const loadTotal = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost/k-shop/amount.php");
  const result = await response.json();
  setTotal(result);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if(orders.length === 0) {
        loadData();
    }
    // you can do the same with checking loadTotal() state
}, [orders]);

console.log(orders);
```

Comment: What would be the point of doing that, though? It'll be very nearly the same as just leaving the array empty, if any orders come back.

Comment: This is going to be a duplicate of any of the dozens of "too many renders" questions that already have answers.

Comment: Problem is still there this if check is only rendering the component for one time when length=0 means at the beginning and it is not rendering the component when data changes in state

Answer (score 0):

Avoid ,non-primitive data types  in dependencyArray ,

```
 useEffect(() => {
    loadTotal();
    loadData();
  }, [total, orders.length]);
```

Comment: I did this but still this is not rendering the component when data changes

Answer (score 0):

every times you "setOrders" means you change the state,every times you change the state,means the "useEffect" will do again.that cause infinite loops.why not try `useEffect(() => {loadData()}, [])`?

Comment: Dear I know I can pass empty array as dependency but then it will just run for once and I want to run function on each new change in DB

Comment: which function can detect the DB changes?"loadTotal"?if the "loadTotal" is a function what can detect the DB changes,maybe you can make a "setInterval" and set total as the dependencies to run the "loadData"

Comment: const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]); Here I am loading my data from DB and it supposed to re-render whenever new change occur at DB thats why I am using **orders** as dependency but the problem is it is causing infinite loop whenever I use it as dependency and I know why because DB always return an object in return and we cant use object as dependency but then the question is how am I supposed to reflect changes back to my App